# How can I reroute a jboss server in IntelliJ so that it doesn't point at the .WAR?

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea

I am hosting a JBoss server locally using IntelliJ-Idea, and am running into a problem routing.

The source files are stored in an artifact named 'web' under a sub-folder named 'resources'.

This means that the default page 'index.html' is hosted locally at

localhost:8080/web/resources/index.html.

How can I change this routing so that

localhost:8080/index.html points to the same file? I ask because a bunch of JavaScript libraries reference the project root, and the web/resources piece of the URL is interfering.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the [Web facet](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/web-ejb-and-java-ee-application-facet-pages.html) of the module, [like this](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/7915/7g9y.png).